# What is RFHUTIL used for?

Tags: ibm-mq

What is RFHUTIL. What are the uses of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [SupportPac IH03](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/uid/swg24000637) page:

> It allows test messages to be captured
> and stored in files, and then used to
> drive WBI Message Broker Version 7
> applications. Output messages can also
> be read and displayed in a variety of
> formats. The formats include two types
> of XML as well as matched against a
> COBOL copybook. The data can be in
> EBCDIC or ASCII. An RFH2 header can be
> added to the message before the
> message is sent.

WebSphere MQ messages can contain a Rules and Formatting Header or RFH for short.  The RFHUtil (and it's client-based companion RFHUtilc) allow for a wide variety of message manipulation with and without these headers.  Because the headers are used extensively by WebSphere Message Broker and for v6 Pub/Sub the utility provides a convenient way to perform ad-hoc testing of message flows, publications and subscriptions.  It also allows the loading and unloading of queues to files or files to queues, for example to perform regression testing against a known workload.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to place or view messages on the MQ remote queue.

> The RFHUtil version 3.5.0 utility
>   program will read data from files
>   and/or queues; write data to files
>   and/or queues and display data in a
>   variety of formats. However, it is not
>   an editor. While the user data portion
>   of the message can be displayed in a
>   variety of formats, it cannot be
>   changed.

Take a look at http://sites.google.com/site/ibmmiddleware/rfhutils

Comment: Hmmm...mixed quality on that site. Some of the links and info are good but some is grossly out of date or incomplete. For example, the "Downloads" page links to V6 client but not the V7 client or any of the trials or the SupportPacs page.  Use with caution and verify against the official pages where possible.